# Rails 4, params not received by controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup a post editing page, with links to edit and delete posts. I'm having troubles because my edit controller somehow doesn't seem to receive the parameters I'm sending. I've printed them out on the page to make sure they're there, and it displays correctly, but when I click the editlink I get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` `Couldn't find Article with 'id'=` .

here's the view with the link: (article.id display correctly on this one)

```
<div id= "articles-index">
    <div class = "row">
        <% @article.each do |article| %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class = "container">               
                <p><%= link_to article.title, article %> | <%= article.updated_at.strftime("%e. %b %Y, %H:%M") %> | <%= link_to 'edit', articles_update_path(article.id) %> | delete</p>
                <h2><%= article.id %></h2>
                </div>                          
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

articles controller:(the ... is where I edited more code out as it's irrelevant to this question)

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController        
    ...
    def update
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])  
    end            
    def manage
      @article = current_user.articles
      @article = current_user.articles.order('id DESC')
    end
    ...    
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:id, :title, :body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

routes:

```
  get 'articles/edit'   
  get 'articles/destroy'    
  get 'articles/manage'    
  get 'articles/show'    
  get 'articles/index'    
  get 'articles/new'    
  get 'articles/update'    
  get 'articles/search'    
  get 'articles/create'    
  get 'sessions/destroy'    
  get 'sessions/new'      
  get 'users/new'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :articles
```

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/Shooshte/topdecka_v2)

Comment: not something daft like params['id'] is it?

Comment: I use the exact same syntax when viewing article, and it works `def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end`, ony there the view code is `<%= link_to article.title, article %>`

Comment: Can you post your articles routes?

Comment: Check your params object in `update` method. When I see `article_params`  method, I think that the structure is {article: {id: 1} }, so if it's true, you should do `Article.find(params[:article][:id])`

Comment: @Vucko updated routes into main post. @MihailPetkov this returns `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Try with article, instead of article.id `<%= link_to 'edit', articles_update_path(article) %>`

Comment: what url you get with `<%= link_to article.title, article %>` and `<%= link_to 'edit', articles_update_path(article.id) %> ` ???

Comment: @ inye when I go to article.title, article it calls the show action in my controller. The url is `http://localhost:3000/articles/6`. With the edit/update/destroy actions the url is `http://localhost:3000/articles/edit.6`

Comment: Did you try `articles_update_path(article)` instead of `articles_update_path(article.id)` ?

Comment: I never see a url with dot there `/edit.6`. Try like @Mihail say `<%= link_to 'edit', articles_update_path(article) %>`

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič delete all article routes, and just leave `resources :articles`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on a link instigates a GET request. I'm guessing the update action on your controller will be expecting the params to be a POST request.

The **edit** action normally handles GET.
The **update** action receives the POST request.

I was trying to find the DHH 2007 Keynote at Railsconf that covers this really well. If you can find it, watch it.

See [CRUD Verbs and Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) at Rails Guides

**UPDATE:** Just seen your routes file. If it's a GET request then just put the URL directly into the browser. e.g.

```
articles/update?id=123
```

See if params[:id] == 123 in the controller. It should be.

**UPDATE 2**

```
articles_update_path(id: article.id)
```

Will generate a params has with an :id key but fundamentally you shouldn't be calling update actions with a GET route.

Comment: I thought about this too, so I tried using an edit path and view instead, same story. `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

Comment: params in a GET request are visible in the URL. You'll see a '?' followed by the param name and the value. Example:
https://www.google.co.uk/?q=example

Comment: the url I get when clicking the link is `http://localhost:3000/articles/edit.6`. If I manually input it the way you suggested it, `articles/update?id=123`, it gets to the right page. I don't really understand what you mean with if params[:id] == 123 is in the controller. The only this I declare in the controller is posted in the post (def article_params). Can you specify how to add this please?

Comment: Try this...
articles_update_path(id: article.id)
You'll get: http://localhost:3000/articles/edit?id=6
As opposed to http://localhost:3000/articles/edit.6
What I meant was put http://localhost:3000/articles/edit?id=6 directly in the browser and you should see something in the params hash with an :id key.

Comment: This got it working as intended. However the url is now `articles/update?id=5` instead of `articles/6/update` . Is this something I should be concerned about? If not, edit out your anwser with the correct comment code, so I can accept it

Comment: Fundamentally, it's not best practice to call an update action with a GET request. If you want to update a resource then it's two stages... stage 1 is to call the edit action that displays the form and stage 2 is to POST/PUT/PATCH those form params. The POSTed params are then picked up by the update action. I think you need to learn about HTTP verbs and it will all make a lot more sense :)
Another thing to do is run

$> rake routes -T

It will show you all the generated routes, the associated verbs and how it extracts things like :id from the URL.

Comment: I think the main problem is that I added routes with rails g controller about 4 times when I figured out how many functions I want and things just got to messy. I'll probably remake the whole thing once I get everything down. Thanks for the help and the documentation link, I'll look into in